# Can anyone help identify which insect is this?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

I know this may not be the right forum for insect identification, but I couldn't find any reliable source of information. Please bear with me

[image: The insect was found on my front door, total length may be about 2 rice grains]

The insect was found on my front door, total length may be about 2 rice grains

You can see wings and slender legs behind the body

I live in India, if it matters.

Comment: I think @picapica is correct. According to [this website](http://wgbis.ces.iisc.ernet.in/biodiversity/sahyadri_enews/newsletter/issue35/article/index.htm), there are about 126 species in India, and you can narrow your search down by checking which genera & species occur in your biogeographic sub-region of India. If you happen to encounter Ephemeroptera again, and want a species-level determination, I would suggest you try to get a photo against a lighter background. The veins on the wings should be visible, as they are important for determination.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is some species of mayfly (order Ephemeroptera). There are some 3000 species in the world so I can't be more precise than that. It looks very pale and it's got a bit of a strange posture, so I'm guessing it just emerged from it's larval skin (in that case the skin should be left behind close by).